# How to deserialize json in VB.Net

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization, json.net

I have a JSON that I want to deserialize.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim client As New RestClient(BaseUrl)
        Dim Respons As Object

        client.Authenticator = OAuth1Authenticator.ForProtectedResource(PublicKey, PrivateKey, Token, TokenSecret)

        Dim request As New RestRequest("xml/devices/list", Method.Get)
        Respons = client.Execute(request)


        Console.WriteLine(Respons.Content)
        Console.ReadLine()

        Dim request2 As New RestRequest("json/sensor/history?id=1556402310&IncludeUnit=1&InculdeHumanReadableDate=1", Method.Get)

        Respons = client.Execute(request2)

        Console.WriteLine(Respons.Content)
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
```

So the JSON is in Respons, but I haven't a clue how to deserialize it

Have not done anything because I don't know how.

This is how the JSON looks like

[image: 1]

Comment: Instead of Image post the text of response .content if you really need some help

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Public Class Sensor_class
    Public Property thing As Integer
    Public Property thing2 As Object
    Public Property results As Result()
End Class

Dim o as Sensor_class

o = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Sensor_class)(Respons.Content)
```